# How to get on one page - section and table which is turned

Tags: tables

Good evening/morning/afternoon

How to get on one page the table (below) and the section (below)? I changed a scale of the table but the table is still on the next page not the same page as text of the section.

Thank you for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,    
bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12

\section*{Základný anglický slovosled oz\-na\-mo\-va\-cej ve\-ty}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    $1.$         &       $2.$     &      $3.$    & 
    $4.$         &       $5.$  \\ 
    \toprule        
    podmet       &     prísudok   &      predmet &     určenie miesta 
                 &  určenie času \\
    (kto?)       &                &  (koho? čo?) &  (kde? kam?)       
                 & (kedy?)\\
    \toprule
    \sffamily{subject}      &   \sffamily{verb}         & 
    \sffamily{object}       &  \sffamily{place}         &
    \sffamily{time} \\
    \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress s2b.dZekt}]} & 
    \textsl{[\textipa{v3:b}]}                      &
    \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress 6b.dZIkt}]}  & 
    \textsl{[\textipa{pleIs}]}                     & 
    \textsl{[\textipa{taIm}]} \\\\
    I            &       learn    &  English    & at home & every 
    evening. \\
    Eva          &      goes      &             & to work & every 
    day.\\      
  \end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image: What I get.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of package `rotating`:

> Sideways figures and tables always take up the whole page.

So it is not possible to have a section title and a `sidewaystable` on the same page.

Maybe you can use `sideways` or `turn` for the table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper, margin=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12

\section*{Základný anglický slovosled oz\-na\-mo\-va\-cej ve\-ty}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{sideways}
    \scalebox{0.8}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      \toprule
      $1.$         &       $2.$     &      $3.$    & 
      $4.$         &       $5.$  \\ 
      \toprule        
      podmet       &     prísudok   &      predmet &     určenie miesta 
                   &  určenie času \\
      (kto?)       &                &  (koho? čo?) &  (kde? kam?)       
                   & (kedy?)\\
      \toprule
      \sffamily{subject}      &   \sffamily{verb}         & 
      \sffamily{object}       &  \sffamily{place}         &
      \sffamily{time} \\
      \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress s2b.dZekt}]} & 
      \textsl{[\textipa{v3:b}]}                      &
      \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress 6b.dZIkt}]}  & 
      \textsl{[\textipa{pleIs}]}                     & 
      \textsl{[\textipa{taIm}]} \\\\
      I            &       learn    &  English    & at home & every 
      evening. \\
      Eva          &      goes      &             & to work & every 
      day.\\      
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{sideways}
  %\captionof{table}{Table caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If a caption is needed you can load `caption` and use `\captionof{table}{...}`.

[image]

Comment: Good. It's a good advice. If I want to get the table on new page the table isn't in the centre of a paper. How to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Then you can use `\clearpage\vspace*{\fill}\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}...\end{minipage}\vfill\clearpage`. And, if the table is allowed to float, you can still use the `sidewaystable` environment. If both `sidewaystable` and `sideways` for tables are used in the same document, I would set option `figuresright` for package `rotating`. Then all these tables are rotated counterclockwise even if it is a twosided document.